# What's the best way to get entities from a object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't know how to describe my case. If the question title is not clear, please help me modify it.

Here is my case, I have a data structure like this:

```
const medicineEntities = {
  1: {name: ''},
  2: {name: ''},
  3: {name: ''}
  ids: [1, 2],
  invalidIds: [3]
};
```

I use es6 `rest/spread` operator and `Destructuring assignment`.

`const { ids, invalidIds, ...medicines } = medicineEntities;`

I just want to use `medicines`. But because of `eslint`, `ids` and `invalidIds` will give me:

`[eslint] 'invalidIds' is assigned a value but never used. (no-unused-vars)`

I know I can disabled some `eslint` rule, the warning will disappear.

But I want to know, how to just get `medicines` without `for-loop`.

`const medicines = medicineEntities.ids.map(id => medicineEntities[id])`;

Comment: Your last line is probably the best you can get, without changing the data structure

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My worry about `for-loop` is performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), you could take an array as target for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and get only the keys which are integer numbers.

Then filter the array with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/) for filtering sparse elements.

`Boolean` works as callback for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and returns for

- a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like `''`, `0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `false`, `null` and some more, or for
- a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, like an object, a not empty string, every number, but not zero, `true`.

In this case, where `undefined` is unwanted, the objects (without `null`) are in the result set.

```js
const
    medicineEntities = { 1: { name: '' }, 2: { name: '' }, 3: { name: '' }, ids: [1, 2], invalidIds: [3] },
    medicines = Object.assign([], medicineEntities).filter(Boolean);

console.log(medicines);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great! I never knew that an array can be used as a target for Object.assign

Comment: can you explain how the `Boolean` works with the filter ?